# Python - List User Pools in Cognito - Filter issues

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-cognito

I have script, which is listing all the user pools, but i am trying to filter against the ID of the pool.  I am new to python (learning a new lanugauge), but filter is not working.

```
import boto3



client = boto3.client('cognito-idp')


def user_pool():
response = client.list_user_pools(
    NextToken="PaginationKeyType",
    MaxResults=20
)

def filter_user_pools():
listpools = client.list_user_pools.filter(
Filters=[{'Id': 'UserPoolId'}])
for list in listpools:
    print(list.Id)
```

Synatx is as follows, that i am trying to filter

```
{'UserPools': [{'Id': 'eu-west-1_asdasdg34', 'Name': 'JenkinsDevelopMarketplace', 'LambdaConfig': {'PreSignUp':...
```

It is complaining so far with Filters.

I am trying to filter for "eu-west-1".

Any advice , appericated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are almost correct. Just lack of python experience.

`lambda x: 'eu-west-1' in x['Id']`, That takes param x and return `True/False` based on condition (`'eu-west-1' in x['Id']`).

```
def get_user_pools():
    response = client.list_user_pools(
        NextToken="PaginationKeyType",
        MaxResults=20
    )
    return response['UserPools'] # this will return list of pool
pools = get_user_pools()
filtered_list = filter(lambda x: 'eu-west-1' in x['Id'], pools) # can change eu-west-1
print(filtered_list)
```